# Pyspark - Data Quality Management with Pydeequ

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, data-quality, pydeequ

I'm trying create Analysis with PatterMatch Analyzer

[PatternMatch docs](https://pydeequ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pydeequ.html#pydeequ.analyzers.PatternMatch)\

But each attempt ends with a 0.0% result evet if I pass r'.*' as regex.

Im trying to catch all strings with 3 _ sign and 2 digits
XYZ_00

```
                    .addAnalyzer(PatternMatch(
                        column = 'MY_COL',
                        pattern_regex = r'^\S{3}.\d{2}',
                        where = None
                ))
```

Has anyone managed to do it ? In [docs](https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ/blob/master/pydeequ/analyzers.py#L649)  i found out something that suggest it is not completed.